# Updating an item in an array passed by reference

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, pass-by-reference, inout

What's the easiest/right way to update an item in an array? I want the caller to have the updated array as well. So:

```
static func updateItem(updatedItem: Item, inout items: [Item]) -> Bool {
        var item = items.filter{ $0.id == updatedItem.id }.first
        if item != nil {
            item = updatedItem
            return true
        }

        return false
    }
```

I want the caller to have the updated items (with the updated item). I think the problem with the above code is that it only updates the local variable item. What's the best way to actually update the relevant item inside the items array?

Comment: What do you want to the `updatedItem` if there's no existing item with the same `id`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do it the same way Superman gets into his tights — one leg at a time. Cycle through the incoming `inout` array and replace any items where the `id` matches:

```
func updateItem(updatedItem: Item, items: inout [Item]) -> Bool {
    var result = false
    for ix in items.indices {
        if items[ix].id == updatedItem.id {
            items[ix] = updatedItem
            result = true
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

Note that this is Swift 3 syntax where `inout` precedes the type, not the label.

You can write it a little more "Swiftily" by using `map`:

```
func updateItem(updatedItem: Item, items: inout [Item]) {
    items = items.map {
        $0.id == updatedItem.id ? updatedItem : $0
    }
}
```

... but that amounts to the same thing in the end.

Comment: I'm returning bool because the caller does some extra things depending on if item was found or not. How can I return false if item was not found in your "swiftily" approach?

Comment: I rewrote the first approach to return a Bool, and I suggest you use that. There is no savings in using the second approach — `map` is still a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are mutating `item` which is merely a copy of the instance in the array (if `Item` is a value type, such as a `struct`, `tuple`, or `enum`), or a reference to it (if `Item` is a reference type, such as a `class). In either case, the array will be unaffected.

You'll need to find the index of the instance within the array, then mutate the array at that index.

```
func updateItem(updatedItem: Item, inout items: [Item]) -> Bool {
    guard let index = items.index(where: { $0.id == updatedItem.id }) else {
        return false // No matching item found
    }

    items[index] = updatedItem
    return true
}
```

This is all rather clunky, though. It would be better if you used a dictionary instead, mapping the `id` to the instance with that `id`. This means you'll have fast, constant time look up, and it'll be way more convenient. Here's how that will look:

```
// Assuming the "id" is an Int
func updateItem(updatedItem: Item, items: inout [Int: Item]) -> Bool {
    return items.updateValue(updatedItem, forKey: updatedItem.id) != nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with the dictionary how will the calling code look?

Comment: The same, you just pass in the new item and the dict of all items

Comment: Hmm, it's saying value of type [Item] has no member index.

Comment: @Prabhu I don't think such a function exists in Swift 2. You can write an extension on Sequence to add it yourself, but really, just use Swift 3

Comment: Hmm yeah, the thing is we are not ready to migrate to Swift 3 yet, so will have to do the extension I guess.